# Custom Theme Extending Layout Declaring New Logo

Tags: magento2, theme

So I have configured a new Magento 2 theme following [this guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html), everything works except my logo is still the default Magento logo.

I added a layout in my custom theme directory with an extension (`default.xml`) like so:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/rnj.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But I get the default logo, although at a different path `http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/MyTheme/default/en_US/images/logo.svg`

So why am I still getting a logo.svg? Do I just delete it or have I done something wrong that makes it not overwrite the default logo?

I am in `Magento ver. 2.1.1` because I had a lot of problems with custom themes in the latest version, which were apparently [source code problems](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7841), so I moved to 2.1.1

Comment: Have u set ur logo from Admin theme & Configuration? Lastly overwrite that file in ur theme